# Shrinkwrap or Skinwrap modeling technique?

Tags: modeling, shrinkwrap

I heard about this technique on a youtube video but when i tried to replicate it it just doesn't work. Essentially the technique consists in model different hard surface parts and then smoothly join them together only with the shrinkwrap modifier instead of boolean the parts and retopologize everything. Here the video, the technique i'm talking about is at the min 16:04

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJbxu_GLMz0&list=WL&index=1&t=1145s

I tried but the final result it wasn't like in the video despite having followed the same process that is just apply the shrinkwrap. Does someone know anything about it? .

Comment: Not sure exactly what your asking but it may be a *SubSurface modifier*.
simply go to the object modifiers tab click add then look for *Sub Surface*. If your using a *Boolean modifier* and this modifier stuff can get tricky.
you'll have to create faces with four vertices for sub surf to work without looking weird.

Comment: we lack informations about why you failed, he explains what he does in the video, he juste project the circle, apply, extrude up, bevel

Comment: My problem is that I don't get the edges of the joints between different pieces as clean as it is shown in the video with the red hydrant example. It is evident that the parts are separate

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you did, you should show some images of your project.

I tried and it looks like the example, he also said that he needed to make some adjustments before the "Apply" to get what he wants.

Just the shrinkwrap modifier with a Wrap method in "Project"

[image]